# TimeZone extra hour with getDSTSavings()

Tags: android, date, time, format

I'm trying to show time saved at GMT+0 on serverside. Was using the code below to show relative time, however, now it gives an extra hour. How can I show relative time span that will work all around the world and timesaving sensitive?
When I don't add TimeZone.getDefault().getDSTSavings() it works as expected. However, before, it was working as expected when I add it.

Couldn't find a changelog for Calendar.getInstance() about it started to include daytime savings or not.

```
android.text.format.DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString(1473846745000L,
    Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getDefault()).getTimeInMillis() +
    TimeZone.getDefault().getDSTSavings(),
    android.text.format.DateUtils.SECOND_IN_MILLIS)
```